# Catch only one specific error in Laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a registration form, which contains the email and password fields. Currently, it returns the following errors in case the user does something wrong:

> The email has already been taken.
>
> The password must be at least 8 characters.
>
> The password confirmation does not match.

However, I want that, when the user errs in the registry, only the error he made appears.  I don't know if it is necessary to show the form, since there are only two `input` fields and a `button`. But, here is the code I made to return the errors:

```
@if(Session::has('errors') || count($errors) > 0)
   @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
     <div>
       <h3>{{ $error }}</h3>
     </div>
   @endforeach
@endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an input like:

```
<input type="text" name="username" />
```

You can get the specific error, in the same view, like this:

```
@error('username')
    <span>{{ $message }}</span>
@enderror
```